# Why doesn't variable_set() work in an installation profile?

Tags: 7, configuration, distributions

I'm writing an installation profile, and I want to display some forms on some pages. The form below intended to set a variable at submission time. It does not work in the profile, but it works on an installed site. Why? Where is mistake?

```
function myprofile_install_mode_form() {
  $form = array();
  $form['myprofile_install_mode'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#title' => st('Please select'),
    '#default_value' => 0,
    '#description' => '',
    '#options' => array(st('Option 1'), st('Option 2')),
  );
  $form['actions'] = array('#type' => 'actions');
  $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => st('Continue'),
  );  
  return $form;
}
// Submit handler
function myprofile_install_mode_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $value = $form_state['values']['myprofile_install_mode'];
  variable_set('myprofile_install_mode', $value);
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "does not work". How do you display the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`variable_set()` works fine in installation profiles ([`standard_install()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/profiles%21standard%21standard.install/function/standard_install/7) uses it), it's more likely that the submit handler for your form isn't being run. I seem to remember having to explicitly set the submit handler for one of these extra installation forms:

```
$form['#submit'][] = 'myprofile_install_mode_form_submit';
```

Try adding a call to `drupal_set_message()` in the form submit handler to make sure your code is definitely being run.